# IEEEtran and the automatic generation of mailto: links

Tags: ieeetran

I wonder what IEEEtran does with parentheses around email links. I noticed that email addresses are automatically converted to links (which is what I want), but parentheses around an email and some more text make the text part of the mailto: link.

Is that not clear enough? Here's a MWE:

```
\documentclass{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}
(e-mail: test@example.com) % result: mailto:e-mail:test@example.com

e-mail: test@example.com   % result: mailto:test@example.com

(e-mail: test@example.com  % result: no link

e-mail: test@example.com   % result: no link
\end{document}
```

I want, of course, in HTML notation

```
(e-mail: <a href=mailto:test@example.com>test@example.com</a>)
```

I could not find anything about this in the IEEEtran or hyperref package documentations, and neither could I find any mailto: handling in the IEEEtran code. What is happening here, and how can I prevent it?

*Update*: The same issue arises without hyperref, and it only happens with words such as "e-mail" or "x-y", not with "email" or "x-" or "-y" for example. Here's an updated and extended MWE:

```
\documentclass{IEEEtran}
\listfiles
\begin{document}
test@example.com           % correct: mailto:test@example.com

email: test@example.com    % correct: mailto:test@example.com

e-mail: test@example.com   % correct: mailto:test@example.com

(email: test@example.com)  % correct: mailto:test@example.com

(email: test@example.com   % correct: mailto:test@example.com

(e-mail: test@example.com) % wrong:   mailto:e-mail:test@example.com

(x-y: test@example.com)    % wrong:   mailto:x-y:test@example.com

(x-: test@example.com)     % correct: mailto:e-mail:test@example.com

(-y: test@example.com)     % correct: mailto:e-mail:test@example.com

(e-mail: test@example.com  % wrong:   no link

e-mail: test@example.com   % wrong:   no link
\end{document}
```

With that MWE, these are the file versions listed:

```
*File List*
IEEEtran.cls 2012/12/27 V1.8 by Michael Shell
ot1ptm.fd 2001/06/04 font definitions for OT1/ptm.
***********
```

Comment: Strictly speaking, and in accordance with the IEEE rules, you are not supposed to use `hyperref` package with `IEEEtran`

Comment: You are right when referring to IEEE PDF guidelines. However, I might like to use IEEEtran for work that might not be published on IEEE Xplore, and above all, I want to *understand* what's happening (and perhaps even, why).

Comment: All the above cases produce links for me.  Which version of the packages are you using? (put `\listfiles` at the top of you document to get that infomation in the log).

Comment: I just checked and did not find any updates to my MikTex 2.9 installation. The file versions are here: http://pastebin.com/6D3ph16k

Comment: If you really have to use it, use inside an `\href` tag and let `hyperref` handle it instead of letting `IEEEtran` parsing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is a bug in Adobe Reader XI 11.0.05 on Windows. Probably on other versions, too; definitely not in Chrome 33.0.1707.0. The pdf files created do not contain any links, instead, they are generated on the fly by the pdf viewer. Hence, Andrew Swann's statement about him getting all links is an as correct observation, probably just using a different viewer.

Annoying! (opinion backed up by personal experience)

Comment: And the problem can be reproduced by copying the text from the generated pdf file into a Word 2010 document and saving a pdf file from there.